# while (!(IFG2 & UCA0RXIFG)); Never receives data

Tags: spi, msp430

I am currently using Code Composer studio version 10. I am working with the following code for SPI implementation. I  can't get the receiver code to work atm. I would like assistance to fix the problem with receive buffer.
`

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include <msp430g2553.h>
/**
 */
char data_send, data_recv;
int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watch dog timer
    P1SEL  = BIT1 | BIT2 | BIT4;
    P1SEL2 = BIT1 | BIT2 | BIT4;
     UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST ;
    UCA0CTL0 |= UCMSB + UCMST + UCSYNC+ UCCKPL;
    UCA0CTL1 |=  UCSSEL_2;
/**
 */
while (!(IFG2 & UCA0TXIFG));
     UCA0TXBUF = 0XAA;
    data_send = UCA0TXBUF;

while (!(IFG2 & UCA0RXIFG));
data_recv = UCA0RXBUF;

   P1OUT |= (BIT5);
    return 0;
}
```

`

I have tried changing the values of the following code, which has not improved the problem.`

```
     UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST ;
    UCA0CTL0 |= UCMSB + UCMST + UCSYNC+ UCCKPL;
    UCA0CTL1 |=  UCSSEL_2;
```

`

Comment: `data_send = UCA0TXBUF;` -- you don't need that assignment.  You already wrote the data.  That register may not be readable.

Comment: UCA0RXBUF__SPI    01111100b   USCI A0 Receive Buffer [Memory Mapped]  
 UCA0TXBUF__SPI    00001111b   USCI A0 Transmit Buffer [Memory Mapped]

Comment: Yes, I know what they do, but you don't need to READ the transmit register.

Answer (score 0):

By writing `while (!(IFG2 & UCA0TXIFG));` you are waiting for a transmit interrupt before you ever send something. Try to first write to the transmit buffer, this will initiate a transfer. Once all bits are transmitted and the buffer is empty, the `UCATXIFG` flag will be set.

I also recommend to read the user's guide, you will find it [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau144).